# Erro ao compilar esse codigo simples no c++

Tags: c++

Comecei a estudar programação ontem, e estava tentando compilar esse codigo porem esta dando erro.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Conta.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){
  Conta umaConta;

  umaConta.numero = "123456";
  umaConta.cpfTitular = "123.123.123-32";
  umaConta.nomeTitular = "Higor";
  umaConta.saldo = 100;

  Conta umaOutraConta;

  umaOutraConta.saldo = 200;
  // umaOutraConta.sacar(200);

  umaOutraConta.depositar(300);

  cout << "Uma conta: " << umaConta.saldo << " Outra conta:" << umaOutraConta.saldo << endl;
 
  return 0;
}
```

Conta.hpp

```
#pragma once

struct Conta{
  std::string numero;
  std::string cpfTitular;
  std::string nomeTitular;
  float saldo;

  void sacar(float valorASacar);
  void depositar(float valorADepositar);
};
```

Conta.cpp

```
#include "Conta.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void Conta::sacar(float valorASacar){
  if(valorASacar < 0 ){
    std::cout << "Nao e possivel sacar valores nevativos" << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  if(valorASacar > saldo){
    std::cout << "Saldo insuficiente";
    return;
  }
  saldo -= valorASacar;
}

void Conta::depositar(float valorADepositar){
 if(valorADepositar < 0 ){
    std::cout << "Nao e possivel depositar valores nevativos" << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  saldo += valorADepositar;
}
```

erro:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc2eSBfs.o: na função "main":
tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:(.text+0xbc): referência não definida para "Conta::depositar(float)"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Precisava ver a linha que usa para fazer a compilação. Eu compilei com o clang assim `clang++ -o main Conta.cpp main.cpp` e com o gcc compilei assim `gcc main.cpp Conta.cpp -lstdc++ -o main` e em ambos os casos alterei o arquivo `Conta.hpp` e adicionei no começo as linhas `#include <string>` e `using namespace std;`

Answer (score -4):

Para dar uma boa resposta, vou dividir minha resposta em 2 partes.

1. Conseguir executar seu código numa boa, eu fiz isso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Conta{
  std::string numero;
  std::string cpfTitular;
  std::string nomeTitular;
  float saldo;

  void sacar(float valorASacar);
  void depositar(float valorADepositar);
};


void Conta::sacar(float valorASacar){
  if(valorASacar < 0 ){
    std::cout << "Nao e possivel sacar valores nevativos" << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  if(valorASacar > saldo){
    std::cout << "Saldo insuficiente";
    return;
  }
  saldo -= valorASacar;
}

void Conta::depositar(float valorADepositar){
 if(valorADepositar < 0 ){
    std::cout << "Nao e possivel depositar valores nevativos" << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  saldo += valorADepositar;
}

int main(){
  Conta umaConta;

  umaConta.numero = "123456";
  umaConta.cpfTitular = "123.123.123-32";
  umaConta.nomeTitular = "Higor";
  umaConta.saldo = 100;

  Conta umaOutraConta;

  umaOutraConta.saldo = 200;
  // umaOutraConta.sacar(200);

  umaOutraConta.depositar(300);

  cout << "Uma conta: " << umaConta.saldo << " Outra conta:" << umaOutraConta.saldo << endl;
 
  return 0;
}
```

###### 1.1 prova

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

###### 1.3 você pode testar aqui: https://www.onlinegdb.com/i4aW1jR3X

2. Acho q o problema é no import do cabeçalho, no header mesmo.

###### 2.2 motivo

Para você fazer um import no header é preciso fazer um arquivo com essa extensão "Conta.h" e não "Conta.hpp"

###### 2.3 referência

- https://www.eventhelix.com/design-patterns/header-file-include/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732978/c-how-to-declare-a-struct-in-a-header-file/21439528

###### 2.4 Solução

```
// Conta.h
#include <iostream>

struct Conta{
  std::string numero;
  std::string cpfTitular;
  std::string nomeTitular;
  float saldo;
  void sacar(float valorASacar);
  void depositar(float valorADepositar);
};

void Conta::sacar(float valorASacar){
  if(valorASacar < 0 ){
    std::cout << "Nao e possivel sacar valores nevativos" << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  if(valorASacar > saldo){
    std::cout << "Saldo insuficiente";
    return;
  }
  saldo -= valorASacar;
}

void Conta::depositar(float valorADepositar){
 if(valorADepositar < 0 ){
    std::cout << "Nao e possivel depositar valores nevativos" << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  saldo += valorADepositar;
}
```

```
// chamando o arquivo header
// com a struct e funcoes
#include "Conta.h"
struct Conta conta;
```

Comment: Essa afirmação é falsa *...Para você fazer um import no header é preciso fazer um arquivo com essa extensão "Conta.h" e não "Conta.hpp"...* e o problema do AP provavelmente, como levantado nesse [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/539070/erro-ao-compilar-esse-codigo-simples-no-c#comment969154_539070), é o desconhecimento do uso da ferramenta de compilação.